# How to correct way to change browser URL and then show pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i click on angular tag browser URL will change and then pop up will appear.

My url is http://www.payallpayments.com/

If you call above URL will automatically redirect to http://www.payallpayments.com/login/?next=/

When i click on SINGUP button it is redirect to http://www.payallpayments.com/recharge and then popup is not appear. How to show popup?

> Script code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.replace("http://www.payallpayments.com/register")
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}

$("#myModal5").click(function(){
  $($(this).data("target")).hide();
})
</script>
```

> HTML code:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" onclick="myFunction()">Signup</a>
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Because you are going to a different page (http://www.payallpayments.com/register), it is this page that needs to have the code to show the popup.  Once you've moved to the second page, the first page no longer exists to show the popup on.

Comment: please note that everything after location.replace has no meaning, it will do nothing, because it redirects you to another page that is loaded.
To show you modal either you need to send a request var to alert you that you need to show it, or by using the cookies..... there plenty of ways to do it.

Comment: Just comment the location.replace stuff i guess :-p

Comment: @RikLewis same content is there in different page also

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI if i comment location.replace stuff it will not redirect right?

Comment: I think you dont even need to redirect, just show the modal that must be independent from location (i mean, the submission action etc...)

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI registration.html has register information. With out redirect we will not get register information

Answer (score 0):

The `location.replace` is triggering a page refresh discards the popup.

I suggest you either remove that or move the `modal('show')` into the `onLoad/documentReady` of the `/register` page so the pop up shows when the page loads.

***EDIT after comments***

You can also use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) especially the `pushState` & `replaceState` functions instead of `location.replace`.

So when you click on Sign Up, you want to use `pushState` to change the url to http://www.payallpayments.com/register (this won't reload the page) and then you can show your popup after.

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI I think he meant that the same modal content is on both pages, which i checked to be true

Comment: @gotomanners i added onload function in my html page still it's working.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka I can see lots of `$(document).ready` in your page, put it in one of them.

Comment: @gotomanner i added code like this. Please check my code $(document).ready(function() {
   $($('#myModal5').data("target")).show();
});

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka Yes I can see that but you have to put it inside a script tag for it to work. 
I think you only need one `$(document).ready` for that page so might want to merge the 3 of them into one.

You should also consider consolidating your javascripts and separating them from the HTML into a separate file.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka the code to display a modal should be  `$('#myModal').modal('show');` not `$($('#myModal5').data("target")).show();`

Comment: @gotomanners yes, i modified it's showing. but first time also it's showing for example: if i call this url http://www.payallpayments.com pop up is showing. i don't want that. when i call http://www.payallpayments.com/register at that point only it will show.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka Then why did you add code to display a modal in the `payallpayments.com` page? I think you can fix that easily.

Comment: @gotomanners No man, Actually there are not separate pages both are same page only that's way it showing first time also.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka You have to look in to the History API especially the `pushState` & `replaceState` functions instead of location.replace. So when you click on Register, you the alter the history state to the new url(this won reload the page) and then you show your popup.